# Class not found exception when trying to create web service client

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am trying to consume a web service from a Java client.

I generated the classes using wsimport:

```
wsimport -keep -verbose http://localhost:5382/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

Code looks something like:

```
private String CreateSalesforceIssue() {

    IssueService service = new IssueService();
    IIssueService binding = service.getBasicHttpBindingIIssueService();

    String issueID = binding.createIssue(type, description, steps, 
                                                    expected, workaround, storage, 
                                                    docType, actions, tools, external, 
                                                    repeatability, workaroundType, severity, 
                                                    pmSeverity, products, extensions, versions, 
                                                    os, status, project, resolution, fixversions);

    return issueID;
}
```

When it hits this line:

```
    IssueService service = new IssueService();
```

Stepping into the code far enough and it gets to javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider and fails there.

On

```
public static Provider provider() {
    try {
        Object provider =
                FactoryFinder.find(JAXWSPROVIDER_PROPERTY,
                DEFAULT_JAXWSPROVIDER);
        if (!(provider instanceof Provider)) {
            Class pClass = Provider.class;
            String classnameAsResource = pClass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
            ClassLoader loader = pClass.getClassLoader();
            if(loader == null) {
                loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            }
            URL targetTypeURL  = loader.getResource(classnameAsResource);
            throw new LinkageError("ClassCastException: attempting to cast" + 
                   provider.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(classnameAsResource) +
                   "to" + targetTypeURL.toString() );
        }
        return (Provider) provider;
    } catch (WebServiceException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new WebServiceException("Unable to createEndpointReference Provider", ex);
    } 
}
```

on this line:

```
if (!(provider instanceof Provider)) {
```

with a ClassNotFoundException: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl

I feel like I am missing something, unfortunately I am not sure what... Do I need to initialize the provider anywhere?

Comment: what versio of java are you using and what, if any, extra jars are on your classpath?

Comment: I am using Java 6. I included the jaxws-rt dependancy in my pom.xml. Unfortunately I don't know how to tell what else is in my class path.

Comment: you don't need the jaxws-rt, it is included in the jre.

Comment: I get a new exception now: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.Messages

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this earlier, but I only just realized it might be important. This is actually for a plugin inside Jira. I'm wondering if there are conflicts between the runtime and the atlassian jars that are included.

Comment: I would start checking the Java version from your plugin code. All `NoClassDefFoundError` you get look like there is a real mess with boot classpath and/or endorsed dirs.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `Provider` class into your `classpath`.
If you use `IDE` you can add the library easily by right click on library and choose "add Jar file" (or something like that!). But if you try to compile and run your application via `terminal` use the following commands:

```
javac -d [bin folder] -cp [jar files] [java source files]
java -classpath [jar files] [Main class]
```

you should split the jar files using `:` in Linux and MAC OS and `;` in MS Windows. As you said this is a web service, I think you are using `IDE` and first solution may help you.

P.S. If you also added this jar file into class path and this `exception` occurs again, please add this jar file into your web server/container library directory. (for example `lib` folder in `tomcat`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm no longer working on that project, but if I get back to it and this helps I'll come back and mark it as the answer. For now I will upvote you.